# Tag for the central nervous system

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has tag [cns-central-nervous-systm](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cns-central-nervous-systm) without any synonyms.

I propose that this tag be renamed [central-nervous-system](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-nervous-system) with synonym [cns](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented as suggested in the question.